# Android CardView - How to fold corner

Tags: android, rounded-corners, cardview, cornerradius

I want to get a CardView with the top-right corner like you can see in the image below, but I have no idea how to do so. It is like a folded paper (with no animation). I don't know if I should make a custom background drawable or how to manage the corner radius to get the desired result. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you get the solution? If yes, kindly share.

Comment: I gave up, I didn't found a satisfaying solution

Answer (score 2):

Also you can create such a drawable programmatically like this:

```
public static final class FoldCornerCard extends Shape {

    private final float foldPart;
    private final Path cardPath = new Path();
    private final Path foldPath = new Path();
    private final Paint foldPaint;

    public FoldCornerCard(int foldColor, float foldPart) {
        if (foldPart <= 0 || foldPart >= 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fold part must be in (0,1)");
        }
        this.foldPart = foldPart;
        this.foldPaint = new Paint();
        foldPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        foldPaint.setColor(foldColor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResize(float width, float height) {
        super.onResize(width, height);
        this.cardPath.reset();
        final float leftFold = width - width * foldPart;
        final float bottomFold = height * foldPart;

        cardPath.lineTo(leftFold, 0);
        cardPath.lineTo(width, bottomFold);
        cardPath.lineTo(width, height);
        cardPath.lineTo(0, height);
        cardPath.close();

        foldPath.reset();
        foldPath.moveTo(leftFold, 0);
        foldPath.lineTo(leftFold, bottomFold);
        foldPath.lineTo(width, bottomFold);
        foldPath.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
        canvas.drawPath(cardPath, paint);
        canvas.drawPath(foldPath, foldPaint);
    }
}
```

And usage example:

```
final ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(
    new FoldCornerCard(Color.GREEN, 0.1f));
shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
shapeDrawable.setIntrinsicHeight(-1);
shapeDrawable.setIntrinsicWidth(-1);
```

You just need to modify my snippet a bit to add round corners.

Answer (score 0):

Look at here https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html
I think this is righ way to use custom layout. 
You could draw it on xml, or use 9-patch png. 

Also you can create own class MyCardView and extends from CardView, then override method `onDraw` and draw CardView like you want, but it is not good idea.

 I would reccomend you use `9-patch image`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using your xml:
Lets Assume our xml shape is called shape.xml
In shape.xml(Which you have to create in your drawable folder..drawable/shape.xml)..
Create your layer list element with its square shape as the background of your xml:

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--Paper-Back-->
    <item
        android:bottom="30dp"
        android:left="18dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/paperBack"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="78dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
    <!--Paper-Back End-->

<!--Fold-->
    <item
        android:bottom="650dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:left="300dp"
        android:right="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/paperFold"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="100dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!--Fold End-->
</layer-list>
```

Then in your colours.xml resource:
Add your colours:

**color.xml**

```
<color name="PaperBack">#A6F5F5F5</color>
<color name="paperFold">#A6DDDDDD</color>
```

In order to achieve the best results:The opacity of your colours as well as the type of colour combination for your paper background and fold colours will have to be taken into great consideration.

Now to apply the paper fold shape..in your main xml, use the shape.xml as the background in your main.xml.

**using shape.xml as the background**

```
 android:background="@drawable/shape.xml"
```

**main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape.xml"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">
.....................
```